# echo $PATH not reflecting saved paths

Tags: macos, shell, path

I have attempted to add, `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/My_Name/desktop/My_Folder"`, to `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile`. I executed the command `source ~/.bash_profile`, `source ~/.bashrc`, and `source ~/.profile` to refresh the `$PATH` and it does reflect that when I execute `echo $PATH`.

However, when I open a new terminal and execute `echo $PATH` it is unchanged.

The issue is my system (macOS Big Sur) will not recognize the updated `$PATH` when I open a new terminal unless I execute the source command every time to refresh my `$PATH`.

For context, I edited all three because I have scoured multiple sites for suggestions and have exhausted all my options.

**Solution: I realized that I was using `zsh`. To change I executed `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change my shell to bash.**

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Shell scripting is on topic, but general macOS usage questions belong on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: You are probably using `zsh`, not `bash`. The appropriate file would be `.zprofile`.

Comment: ```.zprofile``` isn't a file that exists for me. Do I have to create it and then export my path into it?

Comment: Yes, you can just create it when it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution: I realized that I was using `zsh`. To change I executed `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change my shell to bash.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your .profile file in an editor like nano or pico and make sure your command is at the bottom of the file. Also, make sure you close your quotes like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/My_Name/desktop/My_Folder"
```

You might also consider placing the new path at the front like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/My_Name/desktop/My_Folder:$PATH"
```

I have an alias in my profile folder called reBASH looks like this

```
alias reBASH='source ~/.bash_profile'
```

So that when I change .bash_profile, I merely type reBASH, hit enter and it gets applied to the current session ... just something you might consider as a convenience when doing things like this.

Comment: I apologize, there was a mistake in my post. I did close the quotes on my terminal similar to the first line of code you listed. I tried the second line of code and refreshed and it did not work. I am under the impression the point of adding paths to $PATH is to streamline work on the terminal and I am trying to find a way to properly update my path, so I wouldn't have to execute the source command every time.

Thank you for the post, it is appreciated.

Comment: @breadelicious the PATH environment variable in your terminal shell basically says this... when you type in a command and hit enter, the shell will look in every path that is in the PATH variable for the command you are trying to execute, so that you don't have to cd into that folder and then execute your command. If the folder that the program you're trying to run is in that PATH variable, then you can run that program no matter which folder you are currently in. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @breadelicious This is a good read: https://medium.com/@jalendport/what-exactly-is-your-shell-path-2f076f02deb4